# What is best practice for binding dynamic beans at runtime

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have some configuration property defined as

```
@Data
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = RedisClientConfigProperties.CONFIG_PROP_NAME)
public class RedisClientConfigProperties {
  public static final String CONFIG_PROP_NAME = "dao.redis";
  private int database = 0;
  private String host = "127.0.0.1";
  private int port = 6379;
  private boolean enabled = false;
}
```

and the following java classes:

```
public interface IDao {
  Object get(UUID id);
  void put(UUID id, Object item);
}

public class NoOpDao implements IDao {
  @Override
  public Object get(UUID id) {
    return new Object();
  }

  @Override
  public void put(UUID id, Object item) {
    // no-op
  }
}

public class RedisDao implements IDao {
  @Autowired
  private RedisClient client;


  @Override
  public Object get(UUID id) {
    return client.get(id);
  }

  @Override
  public void put(UUID id, Object item) {
    client.put(id, item);
  }
}
```

What I want is to be able to autowire an IDao object into another bean, and the implementation is decided at run time based on the `RedisClientConfigProperties#enabled` field. In Guice, i can do something like the following in a module:

```
class DaoModule extends PrivateModule {
    private final RedisClientConfigProperties configProps;


    @Inject
    public DaoModule(RedisClientConfigProperties configProps) {
        this.configProps = configProps;
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure() {
        if (configProps.isEnabled()) {
            bind(IDao.class).to(RedisDao.class);
        } else {
            bind(IDao.class).to(NoOpDao.class);
        }
    }
}
```

In Spring, it is a little unclear of how to go about doing this. I have found a few different ways to do it, but I'm not sure what is the "Spring way" to do it:

1. Use a @Configuration class with an @Bean method that returns IDao with conditional logic inside the method

```
@Bean
public IDao getDao(RedisClientConfigProperties config) {
  if (config.isEnabled()) return new RedisDao();
  else return new NoOpDao;
}
```

2. Use the [service locator pattern](https://springframework.guru/service-locator-pattern-in-spring/) to create a factory which will return the bean you want
3. annotate the implementations with @ConditionalOnProperty annotations

I'm curious about which of these ways is recommended as I have some reservations about each of them:

1. I would rather not have to manually instantiate the beans and have Springs IOC deal with instantiating the beans as necessary
2. This still creates al of the interface implementation beans and requires any consumer of the bean to know what bean they are asking for
3. Potentially error prone given that it doesn't use the Config properties object, but instead looks directly in your config properties files.

Out of these three solutions, I think I prefer #1 but would love feedback / recommendations.

Comment: Is there a specific reason you're not using the existing built-in Boot support for Redis?

Comment: One of the reasons I'm not using spring data redis is because the RedisTemplate abstraction doesn't offer async get or put methods, so I'm just using Lettuce's RedisClient directly (The example classes i gave above were just simplified for this post, but it actually returns CompletableFuture<>).

Answer (score 1):

Your code seems that its per application, so what I recommend is have all of your properties in the configuration path, and not in a `RedisClientConfigProperties`.

keeping your class but modify it like so:
RedisClientConfig.java

```java
@Data
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "dao.redis")
public class RedisClientConfigProperties {
  private int database;
  private String host;
  private int port;
  private boolean enabled; 
  // public getters and setters
  .
  .
}
```

And in your configuration file:
application.yml

```yaml
dao:
    redis:
        enabled: true
        database: 0
        host: 127.0.0.1
        port: 6379
```

And have your dao be only injected in the context based on the property

> You can have it check if property is defined if you only use prefix to avoid passing boolean

RedisDao.java

```java
@Component
@Primary
@ConditionalOnProperty(prefix = "dao.redis", name = "enabled", havingValue = "true")
public class RedisDao implements IDao {
    .
    .
    .
}
```

This way you will have have your `NoOpDao` be always injected,
Unless the `dao.redis.enabled` is true, then the Redis will override the `NoOpDao` implementation because its annotated with `@Primary`.

Comment: This is essentially what i implemented as option #3 in my post, but with default values in RedisClientConfigProperties in case application.yml doesn't define these configs

Comment: Then option 3 is the most 1) open for change, 2) levarage encapsulation, and lastly follows springs convention with minimal costumizations, so 3) convention over configuration.